# Token concatenation using ## doesn't work?

Tags: c

```
#define DECLARE_TYPE(T)     \
    typedef struct          \
    {                       \
        float value;        \
        int scale;          \
    } ae_T##_t;

DECLARE_TYPE(Q25);
```

This should create type `ae_Q25_t`, but it doesn't work.

How to rewrite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, naturally, it should be `ae_##T##_t`. Note that `_` character in C is not a punctuator, it is a regular "text" character (as opposed to , say, `:`, `,`, space and others). This means that `ae_T` is seen by preprocessor as a single continuous indivisible token, not as `ae` followed by `_` and followed by `T`.

Secondly, keep in mind that it won't work as expected if, say, `Q25` is itself a macro and you want it substituted. To resolve this issue you need a two-tier macro definition

```
#define DECLARE_TYPE_(T)    \
    typedef struct          \
    {                       \
        float value;        \
        int scale;          \
    } ae_##T##_t;

#define DECLARE_TYPE(T) DECLARE_TYPE_(T)
```

But if you want `DECLARE_TYPE(Q25)` to always resolve to `ae_Q25_t` specifically, then you are good as is.

Comment: And here comes the Macros Ninja !

Comment: All examples I've seen when I searched "c token concatenation" use `##` on only right side. And example that compiles is also one-sided `##`: `#define DECLARE_CTYPE(s) \
    namespace s##_space { \
    class s##_; \
    } \
    typedef s##_space::s##_ s;` Very strange, many thanks.

Comment: @Danijel Those example also happen to have a white space before or after the parameter, do they not? In this case you must use the concatenation on both sides because the preprocessor treats `ae_T` as a single token.

Comment: Well, punctuators (like `::`) and whitespace don't merge with identifiers. They remain separate preprocessing tokens, which is why you don't need to do anything extra on the left-hand side of `s` in `namespace s##_space` or in `typedef s##_space::s##_`. Meanwhile, `_` is not a punctuator. It is considered a regular character in a "text", meaning that your `ae_T` is seen as an indivisible whole, not as `ae` followed by `_` and followed by `T`. So `T` simply disappears in your case. The `##` helps you to keep `T` separate from the surrounding text.